# WPF, COM Interop and DoEvents

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, vb6, com-interop

I have a WPF TextBox in a WPF Usercontrol hosted in an element host in a winforms usercontrol. The winforms usercontrol is ComVisible and is now hosted in an old vb6 usercontrol.

I also have a winforms test harness where a form hosts the winforms usercontrol to test behaviour outside of COM interop.

If, in the winforms test harness, I set the backcolor of the winforms usercontrol, it delegates down to the background property of the wpf textbox and successfully changes the back ground of the wpf textbox.

If, in my vb6 test harness, I set the backcolor of the winforms control (now operating via COM interop), I am finding that I need to issue a DoEvents in the vb6 test harness to see the background change.

(I should add  that I've also created a "pure" (non-wpf) winforms usercontrol containing a winforms textbox just to test the vb6/winforms interop behaviour. If I set its backcolor from vb6, I **don't** need to issue any DoEvents to see the change - so it appears that it may be something to do with the wrapping of WPF which means I need to force a repaint of the UI)

Obviously I don't really want to have to issue the DoEvents to get the UI to update but does that sound like correct behaviour?

Here's various code segments - (I'm using an MVVM pattern for the wpf bit)

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ProgId("xxxControls.TextBox")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ITextBox))]
[Guid("...")]
public partial class TextBox : UserControl, ITextBox
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost _textBoxHost;
    private TextBoxExViewModel _viewModel;
    private TextBoxEx _textBoxEx;

    ...

    int ITextBox.Backcolour
    {
        get => this._viewModel.Backcolour.AsValue();
        set => this._viewModel.Backcolour = value.AsBrush();                
    }

    ...
}
```

And some xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="xxxControls.TextBoxEx" ... >

    ...

    <TextBox 
        x:Name="MainBox"    
        ... 
        Background="{Binding Path=Backcolour}" 
        ...
        />
</UserControl>
```

and the viewmodel

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public class TextBoxExViewModel : ViewModelBase
{        

    private wpf.Brush _background = new wpf.SolidColorBrush(wpf.Colors.White);
    public wpf.Brush Backcolour
    {
        get => _background;
        set => SetField(ref _background, value, "Backcolour");
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: What did you do to deserve this punishment? ;) But seriously, if you are forced to use VB6, I'd avoid using 3 layers of "technology wrapping". I'd expect to see all sorts of weird behavior.

Comment: Ha. Many thx. (Legacy app that needs enhancing.)

Comment: FYI  - All that is needed is to add spelling - squiggles etc - to an old vb6 textbox but I couldn't find a simple way of doing it

Comment: Can you try .Refresh instead of DoEvents?

Comment: @BillHileman - thx. Yes I tried that. I thought it was working but it was only cause I was hitting a breakpoint. Removed the breakpoint and there was no update.

Comment: What is your issue with `DoEvents`. It suspends processings of a procedure (usually an event or user initiated procedure). Processes all messages (events) is the message queue and calls sleep in windows with 0 seconds. So your VBA program will process usually user actions (unless you are pretending to be a user). So DoEvents is safe as long as the function where it is used **CAN'T** be re-entered. It is used where you change the user interface in unusual (for Windows) ways (or your procedure is really slow) and need the UI to update.

Comment: Normally I comment about the evils of DoEvents. As it is nearly always used wrongly.

Comment: @CatCat Thx. I guess I've always tried to avoid it at all possible. Although generally, in our app, the appearance of the usercontrol is part of the user configuration, the background of the usercontrol could be updated as part of another process (e.g. to indicate an error/alert state) so it could be called as part of a larger process. I think that is my slight concern and hence the hope of finding an alternative.